# For AWS Data Migration Service, How can we import from S3 bucket to aurora?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

Once I have exported an Oracle database to S3, how do I import it on another account, from S3 to Aurora? Does this have to be done manually with lambda, or does DMS service offer an automated way to read from S3 and provide a replica database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Data Migration Service doesn't have S3 files as a valid option for a data source. It is intended to be used to migrate a live database from one running database server to another:

> **On-premises and Amazon EC2 instance databases**
>
> - Oracle versions 10.2 and later, 11g, and 12c, for the Enterprise,
>     Standard, Standard One, and Standard Two editions
> - Microsoft SQL Server
>     versions 2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012, and 2014, for the Enterprise,
>     Standard, Workgroup, and Developer editions. The Web and Express
>     editions are not supported.
> - MySQL versions 5.5, 5.6, and 5.7 MariaDB
>     (supported as a MySQL-compatible data source)
> - PostgreSQL 9.3 and later
> - SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE) 15.7 and later

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.html

Comment: It does have it as a "target" endpoint though. I guess it's intended for manual imports using lambda. Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure if it is specifically for lambda, but once its in S3 you can use it how you want - but if you are trying to do DB to DB migration, you are likely better of just skipping S3 and going direct from a DB-server source to a DB-server target.